# Does exit node encrypt three times for the return path to local machine?

Tags: exit-relays, encryption

I'm new to Tor, So I read the Short User Manual [here](https://www.torproject.org/dist/manual/short-user-manual_en.xhtml)

I found this image in the link above, I understand Tor on my local machine  encrypts everything thrice, what about the return path? Does the exit node encrypt thrice and the everything in the path does everything in reverse of this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The circuit you established to make the initial request is also used for the response. And it does use layers of encryption on the return path the same way as the request.

Comment: The image on the first post, and the one in "onion routing" wikipedia page, show layers only from client to destination server via 3 nodes... but not the reverse path, so if another image is made to show the return path encryption layers, it will be useful to beginers. Thanks.

Comment: The image on the first post and elsewhere shows bidirectional tunnels.  It is both the out path and the back path.